# need help understanding some aspects of how to use variables from 1 extended php class

Tags: php, class

sorry if this seems like a really newbish question but  i am in need of some help. i am trying to make a dynamic web app but having trouble with grabbing a variable from 1 extended class to another

here is an example of my current attempt so far

```
<?php
    class a {
        public $classb;
        public $classc;

        function load_files() {
            include_once('classb.php');
            include_once('classc.php');

            $this->classb = new classb();
            $this->classc = new classc();
        }
    }
?>
```

and here is the class that contains the variable which i am attempting to grab

```
<?php
    class b extends a {
        public $name;

        public function quessName() {
            $this->name = "john";
        }
    }
?>
```

and this is the class that is trying to grab the "name" variable from c class but i cannot seem to do and php is not even bothering to return an error to at all, am i missing something really basic here... any help appreciated

```
<?php
    class c extends a {
        function retreiveName () {
            echo $this->a->b->name;
            or
            echo parent::->b->name;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want c to extend b (not a). Then in c you can just call $this->name;

Answer (score 0):

In class c you could try:

```
echo $this->$classb->$name;
```

(Since an object of c *is also* an a-object, by definition of extending, you can use $this to access a member variable declared in the a class. Also, you need to put dollar signs in front of member variables.)